# How to Prevent Change Footer Content?

Tags: php, function, footer

I am developing a php script and I think I will distribute free.But I want to keep my name at footer.I created fucntion and encoded base 64.This is ok so far.Name cannot be changed  but my name or base 64 function can be deleted.

**in functions.php**

```
function copyright(){
$decode="TG9yZW0gaXBzdW0gZG9sb3Igc2l0IGFtZXQsIGNvbnNlY3RldHVyIGFkaXBpc2ljaW5nIGVsaXQsIHNlZCBkbyBlaXVzbW9kIHRlbXBvciBpbmNpZGlkdW50IHV0IGxhYm9yZSBldCBkb2xvcmUgbWFnbmEgYWxpcXVhLiBVdCBlbmltIGFkIG1pbmltIHZlbmlhbSwgcXVpcyBub3N0cnVkIGV4ZXJjaXRhdGlvbiB1bGxh";
$decoded = base64_decode($decode);
echo $decoded;
}
```

**footer.php**

copyright();

My question is that how can I create function that checks footer.php content and itself for prevent any editing or removing.

Thank you.

Comment: It's great that you've told us! .......and what exactly is your question? The title does not really explain your intentions in a way that at least I understand.

Comment: The short answer is you can't. Open source it under a license that requires attribution, that's the best you can do.

Comment: I think my question quite explain my intentions. Want to creat function that checks php file content.If content of that file changed or deleted or that file totally deleted , script will stop working until same content and file recovered.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. If your code can be modified by its user, then that user can potentially make modifications to any part of that code, including parts which attempt to detect modifications. You can try to make it difficult to find that code, but you cannot prevent it.

There are some techniques that you can use to prevent your code from being modified at all (e.g, encoding it using a tool like ZendGuard or Ioncube), but those are generally not considered appropriate for "free" scripts, as they make it impossible to detect malicious content.

Comment: I know ioncube and zendguard.I remember from one script that I downloaded before.In that script ,If I delete ioncubed strings , script stops work , if I delete footer.php script stops work and If I edit copyright section in footer .php (he warnep with comments) script stops work.People can do this.Like that script's author.How is not possible ?

Comment: You would have to encode the entirety of your application, not just the part that was responsible for this message.